# Вставить переменную в unshift JS

Tags: javascript

> element.unshift(document.querySelector('[posX = "11"]'))

Вставил в этот код переменную 'width', вместо 11, для адаптивности. Но код ломался, пробовал даже писать:

> let width = 11

Всё-равно не работает.

'Конечный код выглядит так:'

> element.unshift(document.querySelector('[posX = "width"]'))

Буду надеяться на вашу поддержку...

Comment: что и для чего ты тут применяешь не понятно, и чего ты хочешь добиться этим тоже не понятно. Весь код скидывай. И погрузи в контекст читателя. Распиши 
все подробно.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: Простите за беспокойство, смог решить проблему добавив '' и ++:
element.unshift(document.querySelector('[posX = "' + width + '"]'))

Comment: В таких случаях ещё помогают [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).